# ASP.NET and SQL getting values to label

Tags: asp.net, database

I created a table in sql database which has list of prices and Items Name....
I wrote a small coding to get the values of item names into my dropdownlist....
Now,
If i select an item in the dropdownlist, I need the price to displayed in the textbox or label... How can I do this? help me out!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should elaborate your question more. It's not clear what you've tried and what does not work.  [Look here](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) to see how to write good questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways of doing that.
You could
- load price/product as JS name value collection and do it client side - most efficient way
- populate dropdown with productId (value) and description and handle itemindexchanged event and do everything server side - not recommended for a public facing, busy web apps.
- send ajax call to web service to get price (client side) - that when you have a bit more complicated model.

It's up to you to decide.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoPostback` property of the DropDownBox to `True`

Then use something like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```